# Trimble feature locations converted to individual points in Arcmap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, feature-class, trimble, terrasync

I mistakenly collected point features in a Trimble Geo 7X by creating a point, and resuming for each different location (they were right of way survey markers along a stretch of road). Each location is showing up but ArcMap is trying to average every position into one location due to all locations falling under one feature.

Is there a way to extract each location and separate them into individual points within ArcMap , or possibly through something else?

Comment: Can you post an example of the point data that you're talking about? Most likely there is a way to do what you want, but its hard to say without seeing the data.

Comment: How have you output the data from your Trimble device?   Can you please [edit] your question to include this info, and a sample of the data as requested by @DylanHamilton.  Also although you've been a user here for a while, I recommend you take the [tour] which describes our focused Q&A format.

Answer (score 1):

I think this may do what you are asking, but its hard to say for sure without seeing the data. It says it splits multipart features into single features, which sounds like what you need.

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/creating-new-features/separating-a-multipart-feature.htm

Comment: That would work, but unfortunately the way the data was collected was a point feature was created within Terrasync, and each separate location was just resumed instead of hitting Done after the 5 second log. So the data is not a multi-point feature, but each location is showing up separately before Arcmap averages each collected point into 1. Unfortunately I can't share screen shots yet as my boss is working on them on another PC.

Comment: @MrJoshua please edit your question to include this and all relevant information.  Where is each location showing up separately before ArcMap averages them?  In ArcMap or another application?